# Issues with installation of Taguette on my local machine

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-connection, psycopg2

Before installing taguette on a server, I wanted to ensure that I was able to have it up and running on my own machine using the docker tutorial of taguette ([self-host-taguette](https://www.taguette.org/self-host.html)). However I don't seem to be able to make it run, using docker compose or not. Here are my steps:

1. I pulled the taguette docker image
2. I created a docker-compose.yml file with the code given by the site :

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  taguette:
    image: quay.io/remram44/taguette
    command: ["server", "/config.py"]
    ports: ["127.0.0.1:7465:7465"]
    volumes:
      - "./config.py:/config.py:ro"
      - "./data:/data"
```

3. First, I tried here to add the database directly in the compose up (seemed simpler and more elegant). I defined the postgresuser and password, depends_on etc. It didn't work.
4. Second, I created a database on my postgres on my computer to connect that one to my taguette instance. (database name : taguette).
5. In the configuration file I defined the DATABASE_URL as follows : DATABASE = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/taguette"
6. I reinitialized my postgres password and user to match the link.
7. I ran docker compose up, but I get this error :

`psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused desktop-taguette-1  |   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting desktop-taguette-1  |   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

I checked if the port was really 5432, which it is, and if postgres was running, which it is.
I figured that my problem was that I didn't install psycopg2-binary properly.

If that is the issue, how and where do I have to install it ? The documentation from taguette is not clear on this. If there is another issue in my proceeding, please do advise me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this under service in your docker-compose.yml file :

```
services:
  ...what you had for taguette...

  postgresql:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: postgres:16
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - postgresql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=pyuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=taguette
    volumes:
      - pg-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  mynetwork:

volumes:
  pg-db:
```

Then use this URL to connect :

```
postgresql://pyuser:pgpassword@postgresql:5432/taguette
```

Also :
Instead of changing config.py file you can pass a configfile (e.g.: taguette.conf) and run taguette like that :
`taguette --debug server ./taguette.conf`

To obtain the config file you can do this :
`taguette default-config > taguette.conf`